# Teacher Zoom Attendance Tool

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am a teacher designing a tool to take attendance from Zoom usage data (the days we live in!)

Zoom provides reports that you can copy and paste and stay formatted as a table. Like this:

```
Luke Name Name
lr@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:03 AM  09/10/2020 08:33:36 AM  12
Barbara Name Name
bar@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:12 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:57 AM  10
Joaquin Name Name Name
joa@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:12 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:59 AM  10
Rafaella Name Name
raf@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:18 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:55 AM  10
Andrea Name Name
and@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:19 AM  09/10/2020 08:32:14 AM  10
Sara Name Name Name
sar@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:20 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:56 AM  10
```

If this is posted into a text editor or a Google Sheet it does format into rows and columns correctly.

My code right now takes that long string of info and cuts out anything that is not an email and then checks the email against a class list in order to see who was absent. What I now want to do is to make it check for late students. Ideally the user would input the string and the time class started and it would display absent students and separately late students.

I think the part I can't figure out is how the user can copy paste the info into a prompt or into an html textarea and then correctly write it to rows and columns so I can manipulate the data.

Code:

```js
//this function copies the info to a spreadsheet and sets formulas in order to find just emails and check them against a student list

function checkAttendance() {
 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
var response =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Student Attendance", "Paste emails of students who attended.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(response.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {return}
  
  var responseText = response.getResponseText();
  
  var splitText = responseText.split(" ");
  var atHandle = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Attendance Handling");
  
  atHandle.getRange(2, 1, 200, 100).clear();
  
  atHandle.getRange(2, 3).setFormula("=FILTER(B2:B, ISNA(MATCH(B2:B, A2:A, 0)))");
  
  var colNum = getColNum2("Student Email");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  sheet.getRange(2, colNum, rows-1, 1).copyTo(atHandle.getRange(2, 2, rows, 1));
  
  atHandle.getRange(2, 1).setFormula('=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(E2, " "))');
  atHandle.getRange(2, 4).setFormula('=FILTER(A2:A, ISNA(MATCH(A2:A, B2:B, 0)))')
   atHandle.getRange(2, 5).setValue(responseText);
  atHandle.getRange(2, 6).setFormula('=if(AND(IFERROR(SEARCH("@", D2), "") <> "", IFERROR(SEARCH("(", D2), "") = ""), D2, "")');
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Attendance Handling").getRange(2, 6).copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Attendance Handling").getRange(2, 6, 200, 1));
  atHandle.getRange(2, 7).setFormula('=FILTER(F2:F, F2:F <> "")');
 
  
  showAttendance()
  
}

  
function showAttendance() {
  
  var atHandle = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Attendance Handling");
   var rows1 = getLastRow(3);
  var rows2 = getLastRow(7)

  var absent = atHandle.getRange(2, 3, rows1-1, 1).getValues().join("\n");
  var present = atHandle.getRange(2, 7, rows2-1, 1).getValues().join("\n");
 
  
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('attendance'); // Modified
  t.Absent = absent
  t.Present = present
  
  html = t.evaluate().setWidth(600).setHeight(345); // Added

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Class Attendance');
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  
 //style removed for space

</head>
<body>
<form>

  <div>
 
  Absent (in student list but not in pasted values):
    <br>
    <textarea id="tofield" name="tofield" rows="9" cols="60"><?!= Absent ?></textarea>
           <br>
  
  Guests (present in pasted values but not in student list):
    <br>
    <textarea id="tofield" name="tofield" rows="9" cols="60"><?!= Present ?></textarea>
           <br>
           
          


<p>
</p>
   </form>
   
   Note: this information is not saved. Please use or copy and paste this information as needed beforing closing.

<p>
   <button id="btn" style="margin-left: 8px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px" onclick='google.script.host.close();' class="sbtn btn btn-secondary btn-c">Close</button>
</p>

  
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like `google.script.run.doSomething(data)` to pass values from the client-side to the server side code, where `doSomething` is a server side function and `data` is a a variable holding the value / object that you want to pass to the client side.

Note: There are some limitations regarding what values/object types can be passed to the server-side, i.e. Date objects can't be passed but you can pase the a string o the correspoining milliseconds.

---

The following code converts the sample data input into a bidimensional array that can be passed to sheet by using `setValues(values)`.

```js
var data = `Luke Name Name
lr@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:03 AM  09/10/2020 08:33:36 AM  12
Barbara Name Name
bar@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:12 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:57 AM  10
Joaquin Name Name Name
joa@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:12 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:59 AM  10
Rafaella Name Name
raf@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:18 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:55 AM  10
Andrea Name Name
and@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:19 AM  09/10/2020 08:32:14 AM  10
Sara Name Name Name
sar@email.com
09/10/2020 08:22:20 AM  09/10/2020 08:31:56 AM  10`;
const arr = data.split('\n');
const matrix = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length;i = i + 3){
  var row = [arr[i],arr[i+1],
  new Date(arr[i+2].slice(0,22)),
  new Date(arr[i+2].slice(24,46)),
  arr[i+2].slice(48)]
  matrix.push(row);
}
console.info(matrix);
```

I suggest you to use the above on the server side, as mentioned previously, because Date objects can't be passed from client-side to sever-side, just be sure that the Apps Script, the Spreadsheet and Zoom are using the same timezone, otherwise you will have improve it to handling the timezones differences appropiately.

Resources

- [Client-to-Server communication | HTML Service | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, I have used that strategy many times in other projects and would be happy to do it here. What I can't figure out is how to pass the information and write it so that it is formatted into columns and rows correctly. It just passes as a long string. Without needing the time info it's easy to just parse anything with an @ sign but organizing the time info is a bit over my head.

Comment: @Luke then you should narrow the scope of your question a lot...

Comment: @Luke I add a some JavaScript that might help you to build your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén that works great! Only thing is I'm unsure on how to make the size of the range variable to how many students get pasted? Otherwise I get "number of rows does not match..."

Comment: @Luke the number of rows of `matrix` is variable. If you need further details, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object from the parsed out times and compare them. If you can get the string representaiotn of the dat you can pass it to the construcotr of `Date` diruectrly

```
new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
```

Once you have the dates you can use operators to compare them, and determine if the student was late or not.

```
function isLate(classStart) {
  var dateStr = /* get the cell value */
  var studentArrvial = Date.parse(dateStr)

  return studentArrival - dateStr > 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, but I can't get to that point because I can't figure out how to parse it with the date/time correct. It has the entrance time but also the exit and it gets very confusing to me to figure out how to make sure the time is the entrance time and connected with the right student since I don't know how to write the data to a sheet and maintain original formatting.

Comment: @Luke My first though is if you know the format you know how long it'll be and just parse it out from there. The formats you posted look like they are in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format so you know it'll be 22 characters with the AM/PM modfiers

Comment: It would help if you could add the raw format (with changes names) to the answer

Comment: I updated it to show a few students only changing the names and emails. One of the problems with counting the characters is that some students have 2 names, some have 3, and some have 4. I would also worry it would be error prone if not copy/pasted exactly the same and might somehow grab the time exited.

Comment: If they are on seperate lines like this, just split by lines use the name and email lines for the first two values in each row. If you look carefully the last line is double splace deliminated "  " so you can split it with [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and use the resulting array for the last 3 values in each row. From there it will be trivial to pull out the data and time from each row